# Unset WordPress attachment fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove some attachment fields but my code doesn't work. Here's my code in functions.php

```
function filter_function_name( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['post_excerpt']);
    unset($fields['title']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
```

I am using WP 4.9.5 What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Yo can use the attachment_fields_to_edit filter to remove the fields you don't want displaying from the array.

```
    function remove_caption($fields) {
      unset($fields['post_excerpt']); // See wp-admin\includes\media.php line 1071
      unset($fields['title']);
      return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit','remove_caption');
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You just copied the ans from here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/how-can-i-remove-fields-in-the-attachment-editor
This is the exact same filter I showed in my question. How the hell did you get this much reputation?